# Background image on radio button css

Tags: html, css

I am adding background image on radio button. But my issue is image is not on checked or click on radio button(background image).

Here is my code

```css
.form-group input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}
.gender input[type="radio"] + label::after {
  background:url('img/male.png') no-repeat -7px -81px;
  width: 28px;
  height: 56px; }
.gender input[type="radio"]:checked + label::before {
  background:url('img/m-f-icon.png') no-repeat;
  width: 28px;
  height: 56px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  content: ' ';
  margin-right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-position-x: -45px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group gender">
  <label class="control-label col-xs-2">I'm a</label>
  <div class="col-xs-1">
    <input type="radio" class="male" name="genderRadios" value="male">
    <label class="radio-inline gender"></label>                            
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-1">
    <input type="radio" class="female" name="genderRadios" value="female">
    <label class="radio-inline gender"></label>                            
  </div>
</div>
```

Kindly advise me any solution.

Comment: Can you link a working example of this?

Comment: Firstly your div `div class="form-group gender">` does not have an opening tag. Also your css is not valid `cursor: pointer;sor:pointer;` should be `cursor: pointer;`

Comment: opening tag is missing in this code but on file I have opening tag edited my code.

Comment: Ok. Can you create a demo of your current code please and post the link on here. Create here https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Your `label` tags do not link with your `<input type="radio">` see documentation for correct use of `label` tags with radio buttons http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_label_for.asp

Comment: here is the link https://jsfiddle.net/hpxq71b6/ 
I have changed background image with bg-color.

Answer (score 0):

Please find demo below I have put together, this is the correct structure you should be using with the appropriate `for` specified on each of your labels that match the related radio button. You can switch out the background colours for background images of your choice.

JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/kdrh56md/